# Binary Interpolation Searching - Cant make it work

Tags: c++, search

I got an exercise in the university to make the Binary Interpolation Searching
Program . But i cant make it work as it should. Sometimes is works and some other not...They gave us the basic program but it was not correct..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void bin(int mat_size, double *mat, int key){
    int left = 0;
    int right = mat_size;
    int mid;
    mid = (mat_size * (key - mat[left]) / (mat[right] - mat[left])) + 1;
    while(key != mat[mid]){
        int i = 0;
        mat_size = right - left +1;
        if(key >= mat[mid]){
            while(key > mat[(int)(mid  + i * sqrt(mat_size) - 1)]){
                i++;
            }
            right = mid + i * sqrt(mat_size);
            left = mid  + (i - 1) * sqrt(mat_size);
        }
        else if( key < mat[mid]){
            while(key <  mat[(int)(mid  - i * sqrt(mat_size) + 1)]){
                i++;
            }
            right = mid - (i - 1) * sqrt(mat_size);
            left = mid - i * sqrt(mat_size);
        }
        mid = left + ((right - left + 1) * ((key -  mat[left]) / (mat[right] - mat[left])));
    }
    if(key == mat[mid]){
        cout<<mat[mid];
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Key not found";
    }
}



int main()
{
   cout<<"Hello enter the size of the array!"<<endl;
   int matrix_num;
   cin>>matrix_num;
   cout<<"Enter the values of the array"<<endl;
   cout<<"Caution elements must be sorted in order to use Binary Search"<<endl;
   double *matrix;
   matrix = new double[matrix_num];
   for(int i=0; i<matrix_num; i++){
     cin>>matrix[i];
   }
   cout<<"Enter a key you wish to search for"<<endl;
   int key;
   cin>>key;
   bin(matrix_num, matrix, key);

   delete [] matrix;
}
```

I worked on it for hours but still crashing....
So this is what i did :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


//Binary Interpolation Searching !

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello enter the size of the array!" << endl;
    int matrix_num;
    cin >> matrix_num;
    cout << "Enter the values of the array" << endl;
    cout << "Caution elements must be sorted in order to use Binary Search" << endl;
    int  *matrix;
    matrix = new int[matrix_num];
    for (int i = 0; i<matrix_num; i++) {
        matrix[i] = i ;
        cout << matrix[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter a key you wish to search for" << endl;
    int key;
    cin >> key;

    int left = 1; // aristera =0
    int right = matrix_num - 1; // de3ia = teleuteo stoixeio
    int mid; // kentro
    int flag = 0;


    if (key <= matrix[right]) {
        mid = (matrix_num * (key - matrix[left]) / (matrix[right] - matrix[left])) + 1;


        while ((key != matrix[mid]) && (flag == 0)) {

            int i = 0;

            matrix_num = right - left + 1;


            if (key >= matrix[mid]) {
                while (key > matrix[(int)(mid + i * sqrt(matrix_num) - 1)]) {
                    i++;

                }
                right = mid + i * sqrt(matrix_num);
                left = mid + (i - 1) * sqrt(matrix_num);

            }
            else if (key < matrix[mid]) {
                while (key <  matrix[(int)(mid - i * sqrt(matrix_num) + 1)]) {
                    i++;

                }
                right = mid - (i - 1) * sqrt(matrix_num);
                left = mid - i * sqrt(matrix_num);

            }



            if (matrix[left] == matrix[right]) {
                flag++;
            }


            mid = left + ((right - left + 1) * ((key - matrix[left]) / (matrix[right] - matrix[left])));



        }

    }

    if (key == matrix[mid]) {
        cout << matrix[mid];
    }
    else {
        cout << "Key not found"<<endl;
        system("Pause");
    }

  delete[] matrix;
}
```

In my code(the second):

```
In the first question "Hello enter the size of the array!":
Input:500
In the second question "Enter a key you wish to search for":
Input:499
```

Output:---
Crashing..

```
In the first question "Hello enter the size of the array!":
Input:500
In the second question "Enter a key you wish to search for":
Input:498
```

Output:---
Never ends....

Also when i change the "for" loop in the beggining (to fill the array) in line 22: matrix[i] = i; and change it to matrix[i] = i*5 ;
so i can test what happens when it cant find it...It never ends too....

```
In the first question "Hello enter the size of the array!":
Input:500
In the second question "Enter a key you wish to search for":
Input:498
```

Output:---
Never ends....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Time to drop your code into a debugger and see where and why it's crashing.

Comment: You should also try and use Standard Library containers like `std::vector` in preference to C-style arrays whenever possible. These provide significantly more functionality and are easier to pass around, plus if used properly will make memory management a lot less messy.

Comment: Change this: `matrix = new int[matrix_num];` to this: `std::vector<int> matrix(matrix_num);` -- Then use `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements in matrix.  Don't be surprised if you now get an `out_of_range` exception instead of a crash.  Fix the boundary issues reported by the exception-- test -- change vector back to the abominable `matrix = new int[matrix_num];`. You've fixed your bug.

Comment: The last part of changing back the vector to the abomination is optional.

Comment: @nwp -- Just in case there is the "you can't use vector" stipulation a lot of these courses seem to have.

Comment: @OP -- Why are you starting out with 500 items anyway?  Why not start with 5 or 6 items and make sure it works for those values.

Comment: And [look here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ef91b821fcdfa35), there you go.  Please address the issue brought up by that strange index you're using at the call to `at()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the answer !  I got the message but i dont know how to fix it at all (I am new to programming):(  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 6) >= this->size() (which is 6) )
Can you help me fix it ? Thanks

Comment: The error is stating that either 1) Your array is too small, or 2) Your index is too large, or 3) Your calculation of the index is not right (related to 2).  You have an array to hold 6 items, and you're accessing one beyond what is allowed.

Comment: According to the book they gave us the calculations should be correct:
http://imgur.com/rkX4gQl . I tested the code that you provided and i cant understand why i get the out of range exception since the key is inside the vector

Comment: You are computing `6` as the index, and that is out of bounds of the array -- maybe when you use the book calculation, the value is `5`, but floating point calculations do not work the same as grade school arithmetic due to the computer using binary floating point (thus inexact).  Concentrate on the values you're using at that one line that is giving you `6` as the index value -- that is what this all boils down to.  Besides, isn't debugging supposed to be *your* exercise?  You know where the error is, *why* the error is there is now your job.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Is not debbuging my exercise at all . The code that gave should work well . Our exercise is to test the best and worst case of this programms . Anyway i will try fix it . Thank you again