# Binary Interpolation Search cannot find the number im looking for (C)

Tags: c, search, binary, interpolation

I have an assignment demanding I utilize the algorithm of Binary Interpolation Search in order to find a number and its position in an array, which I'm entering through the keyboard. Unfortunately, while I get no errors, the program returns nothing even though it asks me to enter a number! If you have any idea what might be going wrong it will be helpful!

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int bis(int Array[],int x)
{
    int i;
    int hitpos;
    int left = 0;
    int right = sizeof(Array);
    int size = right - left + 1;
    int next;
    int a = x - Array[left];
    int b = Array[right]-Array[left];
    int c = right - left + 1;
    int d = (int)(i*sqrt(size));
    next = (size*a/b+1);
    do
    {
        i=0;
        size = right - left +1;
        if(x >= Array[next])    
        {
            do
            {
                i = i+1;
                right = next + i*sqrt(size);
                left = next + (i-1)*sqrt(size);
            }
            while(x > Array[next + d -1]);
        }
        else if(x < Array[next])
        {
            do
            {
                i = i+1;
                right = next -(i-1)*sqrt(size);
                left = next - i*sqrt(size);
                next = left + (c*a/b);
            }
            while(x < Array[next - d + 1]);
        }
        else if(x = Array[next])
        {
            return next;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }   
    }
    while (x != Array[next]);


}

int main()
{
    int Array[] = {1,8,10,14,31,55,56,78,87,101};
    printf("Please provide a number for binary interpolation search\n");
    int x;
    scanf("%d", x);
    int hit;
    hit = bis(Array,x);
    if (hit != -1) 
    {
        printf("Element found at index %d", hit); 
    }
    else
        printf("Element not found."); 
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: This `int right = sizeof(Array);` does not what you expect. Even if you call a pointer an "Array" it stays a pointer... ;) - a pointer typically has the size of 4 or 8 bytes depending on the OS the code is compiled for.

Comment: `if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) /* error */;` you must use `&` to pass **the address** of `x` to `scanf()`; the check of the return value is nice ... and may warrant a few extra points from your teacher :)

Comment: @pmg even when I put &  before x in  the `scanf("%d", x) `  it still does the same thing as before...

Comment: @alk I changed it to `int right = n;` and in my main I added this piece of code: `int n = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0]);` it still didn't change anything

Comment: `if(x = Array[next])` ==> `if (x == Array[next])` **turn on your compiler warnings and mind the warnings**

Comment: @pmg well even though that kinda worked, now it does not display the correct position of the number I entered and it only goes this far with the number 8 which is 2nd in my array and I get an answer: Element found at index 8, while the answer should have been: Element found at index 2. And that just for this specific number... if I input anything else it just displays nothing! By the way, the warnings are ON but it did not give out any for that specific line or any other line!

Comment: Do you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644787/binary-interpolation-searching-cant-make-it-work ?

Comment: @bruno I will check it out and get back to you ASAP !

Comment: @bruno well I checked the question you provided but I am really not able to understand why even though we follow the exact same algorithm ( we probably go to the same uni :) ) I am still not able to find the element in my array and print its location on the array! The weird thing is that once in a blue moon it will find the element 8 but it will pinpoint its location at index 8 while it should be index 2!

Comment: I looked at your proposal and have some remarks about (some already given in the remarks above), but because _d_ is non initialized (because of _i_) I cannot try a partially corrected code to solve all. I know what interpolation search is but I don't know what binary interpolation search is and found nothing about it except the link I given you here

Comment: @bruno I also found nothing online about BIS because apparently, it is really not efficient but I used a,b,c,d variables the way I did, because if I tried in `while(x > Array[next + d -1]);` and in `while(x < Array[next - d + 1]);` to skip the variables so they are not  non initialized it gave me an error that the array expects an integer while I provide something that it is not an integer! Again thanks for all that help!